# Equation of a curve passing through the point of intersection of two curves.

Tags: coordinate-systems

It is given in my book that, equation of any curve passing through the point of intersection of two curves $C_1=0$ and $C_2=0$ , is given by $a \cdot C_1+b \cdot C_2=0$, where $a$ and $b$ are real parameters. I wanted to know the proof of this fact. I have proved the above result specifically for lines and circles but I am not able to prove the result in general. Please guide me.

Comment: @hdighfan you proved that any curve of the form aC1+bC2=0 will pass through the point of intersection of C1=0 and C2=0 ,but how can we be sure that any curve passing through the point of intersection of C1=0 and C2=0 can be written as  aC1+bC2=0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your curves are characterised by $C_1(x,y) = 0$ and $C_2(x,y) = 0$. If some point $x, y$ satisfies these, then $aC_1(x,y) + bC_2(x,y) = a \cdot 0 + b \cdot 0 = 0$, as required.